# Programming with Jolie?

Tags: ide, jolie

I need to use the programming language "Jolie" for a school project, and I installed the interpreter successfully. But now I dont know how to actually code with this language. Especially in what IDE. I tried to do it with the CMD in Windows (just created a new file "test.ol" with a simple "Hello World" command in it and executed it with "jolie test.ol") but it didnt work. 
All I get is the following:

jolie.lang.parse.ParserException: C:\Users\Marco\test.ol:2: error: Invalid token encountered. Found token type ID, token content â
        at jolie.lang.parse.AbstractParser.throwException(AbstractParser.java:241)
        at jolie.lang.parse.OLParser._parse(OLParser.java:223)
        at jolie.lang.parse.OLParser.parse(OLParser.java:185)
        at jolie.Interpreter.buildOOIT(Interpreter.java:1251)
        at jolie.Interpreter.init(Interpreter.java:1053)
        at jolie.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:1139)
        at jolie.Jolie.main(Jolie.java:60)

Does anybody have a clue for me how to actually use this language? I would prefer an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse. Or are their any extensions for this language in a common IDE?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You may have some character enconding issues. Are you copying and paste the code? If so, don't!

Just type in the code yourself in any editor, notepad or just nano. It should work then!

Comment: It worked for me, I think it should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As woland noted, it's an encoding issue, which is that

> Found token type ID, token content â at

at the beginning of the error trace.

Regarding IDEs, there are some plugins that provide syntax highlighting, syntax checking, etc. for editors like Atom, Sublime Text, and Kate. You can find instructions clicking on the "Editors & Plug-ins" tab under the [Downloads](https://www.jolie-lang.org/downloads.html) page on the Jolie website.